# Access path params from outside the main controller with Quarkus and Resteasy

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

I'm using Resteasy with Quarkus (`io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy`).

I have a path with params declared on a controller.

```java
@RequestScoped
@Path("/v1/domain/{domain}/resource")
public class MyRestController {

    @POST
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(Entity entity) {
        // here I create a new entity...
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        // get and return the entity...
    }

}
```

I would like to retrieve the `domain` path param from outside this controller, in a provider marked with `@Dependent` for example, or in any interceptor that process the incoming request.

```java
@Dependent
public class DomainProvider {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public Domain domain() {
        // retrieve the path param here !
    }
}
```

I didn't find a way to do that, nor documentation about this.

I tried both:

- injecting `io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext` with `@Inject` and access `routingContext.pathParams()`
- using `ResteasyProviderFactor` to recover the request context data

In both case, there is no path parameter : the request path is resolved as a simple string, containing the actual URL the client used to contact my web service.

**Edit:**
As a workaround, in my `DomainProvider` class, I used the `routingContext` to retrieve the called URL and a regular expression to parse it and extract the domain.

Comment: Have you tried `@PathParam("domain") String domain` (in the method signature)?

Comment: The `@PathParam` annotation is not accepted outside the controller. Quarkus injection throws an error.

Comment: As proposed on the method, not on the class, e.g. `public Response get(@PathParam("domain") String domain, @PathParam("id") String id) {`

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I know how to access path params from inside the controller, as I did for the `id`. I want to access the path params from outside this class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this.

You need to pass the param from the JAX-RS resource on down to whatever piece of code needs it